For extracting stocks from Yahoo, pdr_override no longer works
I was told that I had to override pdr with yahoo finance to extract data-now it no longer works.
Here's the code:
import numpy as np  
from datetime import datetime  
import pandas_datareader as pdr  
from scipy.stats import norm
import yfinance as yfin

days_to_test = 30  
days_to_predict = 1  
simulations = 1000  
ticker = 'MSFT'

yfin.pdr_override()

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=datetime(2000, 1, 1), end=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['Close']

I thought it would work by using pdr_override, but it didn't work, unlike what many others have said.
